# Unable to test secure resources with Dropwizard

Tags: java, jackson, dropwizard

I'm trying to write a test for a secure resource in my Dropwizard application (I'm using Dropwizard 0.8.1).  The authorization works fine when I run the application, but I can't seem to write a test that will work.  The code is largely based off the example Hello World application, and I keep getting a 401 despite passing in the correct authorization headers. I have the following:

**HelloWorldResource**

```
package com.example.helloworld.resources;

import com.example.helloworld.core.Saying;
import com.example.helloworld.core.User;
import com.google.common.base.Optional;
import com.codahale.metrics.annotation.Timed;
import io.dropwizard.auth.Auth;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

@Path("/hello-world")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class HelloWorldResource {
    private final String template;
    private final String defaultName;
    private final AtomicLong counter;

    public HelloWorldResource(String template, String defaultName) {
        this.template = template;
        this.defaultName = defaultName;
        this.counter = new AtomicLong();
    }

    @GET
    @Timed
    public Saying sayHello(@QueryParam("name") Optional<String> name) {
        final String value = String.format(template, name.or(defaultName));
        return new Saying(counter.incrementAndGet(), value);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("secure")
    @Timed
    public Saying sayHelloSecurely(@Auth User user) {
        final String value = String.format(template, user.getName());
        return new Saying(counter.incrementAndGet(), value);
    }
}
```

**Saying**

```
package com.example.helloworld.core;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;

public class Saying {
    private final long id;

    @Length(max = 3)
    private final String content;

    @JsonCreator
    public Saying(@JsonProperty long id, @JsonProperty String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

**Authenticator**

```
package com.example.helloworld.auth;


import com.example.helloworld.core.User;
import com.google.common.base.Optional;
import io.dropwizard.auth.AuthenticationException;
import io.dropwizard.auth.Authenticator;
import io.dropwizard.auth.basic.BasicCredentials;

public class SimpleAuthenticator implements Authenticator<BasicCredentials, User> {
    public Optional<User> authenticate(BasicCredentials credentials) throws AuthenticationException {
        if ("secret".equals(credentials.getPassword())) {
            return Optional.of(new User(credentials.getUsername()));
        }
        return Optional.absent();
    }
}
```

**SecureTest**

```
package com.example.helloworld.resources;

import com.example.helloworld.auth.SimpleAuthenticator;
import com.example.helloworld.core.Saying;
import com.example.helloworld.core.User;
import io.dropwizard.auth.AuthFactory;
import io.dropwizard.auth.basic.BasicAuthFactory;
import io.dropwizard.testing.junit.ResourceTestRule;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.filter.RolesAllowedDynamicFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory;
import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;

public class SecureHelloWorldResourceTest {
    @ClassRule
    public static final ResourceTestRule resources =
            ResourceTestRule.builder()
                    .addProvider(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class)
                    .addProvider(AuthFactory.binder(new BasicAuthFactory<User>(new SimpleAuthenticator(),
                            "Authentication Realm",
                            User.class)))
                    .addResource(new HelloWorldResource("Hey There %s", "DefaultName"))
                    .build();

    @Test
    public void testGetPerson() {
        resources
                .client()
                .target("/hello-world/secure")
                .request()
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic Z29vZC1ndXk6c2VjcmV0").get(Saying.class); //Decodes to "good-guy:secret"

    }
}
```

**Update**

After reading https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/922 I started using a Grizzly container and now I'm getting a new error relating to the serialization of Saying:

**Stacktrace**

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error reading entity from input stream.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:868)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:785)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:790)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$500(JerseyInvocation.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:687)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:683)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:411)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:307)
    at com.example.helloworld.resources.SecureHelloWorldResourceTest.testGetPerson(SecureHelloWorldResourceTest.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at io.dropwizard.testing.junit.ResourceTestRule$1.evaluate(ResourceTestRule.java:199)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Argument #0 of constructor [constructor for com.example.helloworld.core.Saying, annotations: {interface com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator=@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator(mode=DEFAULT)}] has no property name annotation; must have name when multiple-parameter constructor annotated as Creator
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:267)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:242)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:143)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:439)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._findRootDeserializer(ObjectReader.java:1564)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bind(ObjectReader.java:1403)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:858)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.readFrom(ProviderBase.java:808)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1085)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:853)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument #0 of constructor [constructor for com.example.helloworld.core.Saying, annotations: {interface com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator=@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator(mode=DEFAULT)}] has no property name annotation; must have name when multiple-parameter constructor annotated as Creator
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._addDeserializerConstructors(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:508)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._constructDefaultValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:325)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:258)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:216)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:143)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:405)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:354)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:262)
    ... 53 more


Process finished with exit code -1
```

**Secure Test**

```
package com.example.helloworld.resources;

import com.example.helloworld.auth.SimpleAuthenticator;
import com.example.helloworld.core.Saying;
import com.example.helloworld.core.User;
import io.dropwizard.auth.AuthFactory;
import io.dropwizard.auth.basic.BasicAuthFactory;
import io.dropwizard.testing.junit.ResourceTestRule;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.filter.RolesAllowedDynamicFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory;
import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;

public class SecureHelloWorldResourceTest {
    @ClassRule
    public static final ResourceTestRule resources =
            ResourceTestRule.builder()
                    .addProvider(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class)
                    .setTestContainerFactory(new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory())
                    .addProvider(AuthFactory.binder(new BasicAuthFactory<User>(new SimpleAuthenticator(),
                            "Authentication Realm",
                            User.class)))
                    .addResource(new HelloWorldResource("Hey There %s", "DefaultName"))
                    .build();

    @Test
    public void testGetPerson() {
        resources
                .getJerseyTest()
                //.client()
                .target("/hello-world/secure")
                .request()
                    .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic Z29vZC1ndXk6c2VjcmV0").get(Saying.class);

    }
}
```

Comment: You are having issue in Authentication. 401 means forbidden; this exception you are seeing has something to do with your security only. You are not having any issue with your params, if you see 400 then its parsms issue.

Comment: For update : Try providing a default constructor

Comment: I believe the 401 is a result of this - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/2H0uemf8cf4

Comment: And I want the Saying to be immutable so do not want a default constructor

Comment: ya so thats what am telling your credentials are not Authenticated because the chain is not ending correctly. You have to find out a way to complete the chain. Also can you use Spring security instead of Dropwizard? (just asking)

Comment: So it seems like to complete the chain I need to use what I did in the update which leads to the serialization error.  And I don't plan on using any other security framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the serialization errors in the update by annotating the params to the constructor with named JsonProperties, which seems a little redundant.

```
public class Saying {
    private final long id;

    @Length(max = 3)
    private final String content;

    @JsonCreator
    public Saying(@JsonProperty("id") long id, @JsonProperty("content") String content) {//Note the addition of the ("id") and ("content") 
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

And the test now looks like this:

```
package com.example.helloworld.resources;

import com.example.helloworld.auth.SimpleAuthenticator;
import com.example.helloworld.core.Saying;
import com.example.helloworld.core.User;
import io.dropwizard.auth.AuthFactory;
import io.dropwizard.auth.basic.BasicAuthFactory;
import io.dropwizard.testing.junit.ResourceTestRule;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;

import javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;

public class SecureHelloWorldResourceTest {
    @Rule
    public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();
    @ClassRule
    public static final ResourceTestRule resources =
            ResourceTestRule.builder()
                    .setTestContainerFactory(new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory())
                    .addProvider(AuthFactory.binder(new BasicAuthFactory<User>(new SimpleAuthenticator(),
                            "Authentication Realm",
                            User.class)))
                    .addResource(new HelloWorldResource("Hey There %s", "DefaultName"))
                    .build();

    @Test
    public void testAuthorizedRequest() {
        Saying result = resources
                .getJerseyTest()
                .target("/hello-world/secure")
                .request()
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic Z29vZC1ndXk6c2VjcmV0").get(Saying.class);//good-guy:secret

        Assert.assertEquals("Hey There good-guy", result.getContent());
    }

    @Test
    public void testDeniedRequest() {
        exception.expect(NotAuthorizedException.class);
        resources
                .getJerseyTest()
                .target("/hello-world/secure")
                .request()
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic YmFkLWd1eTpwYXNzd29yZA==").get(Saying.class);//bad-guy:password


    }
}
```

Comment: Great am glad you solved it and how did you complete the chain can you explain?

Comment: It was done using the .setTestContainerFactory(new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory()) in the update to the test, I'll update the answer with the full test case as well